# How to pass an array of input parameters in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, scipy

## I want to use scipy.optimize.minimize to solve for a set of parameters by  minimizing an error function.

The function called "error" returns the squared error for the function that I am trying to find z1,z2,z3(the parameters) for.

I have an array of x(called "b" in the function) and y(called "real" in the function) values.

The code below works fine if I set x and y to some integer, but not if I try to pass in an array of x and y values, to act as the variable "b" and "real" in the equation to be minimized.

Trying to pass in an array of X and Y values results in the error pasted below.

Is there a way to pass in arrays to act as a variable in an equation for the minimize function, instead of just a single integer?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize

#dataset file, with a column named x,y with 1000 rows
f = pd.read_csv('Test_Data_.txt', sep='\t')

#initial guess
x0 = [1, 2, 3]

#f['x'] and f['y'] are columns with 1000 rows
#x = f['x'].values
#y = f['y'].values

x = 1 #these parameters work fine
y = 4

#a function called inside the function to be minimized
def est(z1, z2, z3, b):

    return z1 * b**2 + z2 * b + z3

#function to minimize
def error(x, real, b):

    return (real - est(x[0], x[1], x[2], b))**2

print(minimize(error, x0, args = ( x, y), method='BFGS', tol=1e-6))
```

Feeding in the array of x and y values produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "problem1.py", line 24, in <module>
    minimize(error, x0, args = ( np.array(list(f['y'].values)), np.array(list(f['x'].values))), method='BFGS', tol=1e-6)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 595, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 970, in _minimize_bfgs
    gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 300, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 730, in approx_fprime
    return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 670, in _approx_fprime_helper
    grad[k] = (f(*((xk + d,) + args)) - f0) / d[k]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are passed as is to `error` as the `real` and `b` parameters.  The `args` in the called expression is the the `args` in the traceback.   As a general rule these `scipy` functions can solve or minimize for one set of conditions (as defined by `args`) at a time.  `x0` is varied during the solution, but `args` is not.

Comment: Or to put it another way, if you want to pass arrays in `args` your `error` function has to be able to work with array inputs.